# Zabbix with Fortimanager

Tags: monitoring, snmp, zabbix, fortigate, fortinet

I am seeking assistance with configuring Zabbix to monitor FortiGates that are managed by FortiManager. Despite configuring FortiManager with SNMP and adding a host for it in Zabbix, I am not seeing any results in monitoring the managed FortiGates(8 of them). I am curious if this is a feasible configuration. aka I want to add just fortimanager and want all of my fortigates to be detected and then monitored, i found templates online that cna monitor but i could first try it with the fortigate SNMP/Http template.

Additionally, I attempted to enable SNMP on one of the FortiGate interfaces and added the corresponding SNMP settings with the same community ID used in FortiManager. Unfortunately, no observable changes occurred. I am wondering if installing a Zabbix agent on the FortiManager machine is necessary to collect logs from all FortiGates. Alternatively, should I add each FortiGate individually to Zabbix as separate hosts? is there any solution without adding host by host? thank you